# randomly sample from two distributions but with one value always greater than the other

Tags: sampling, simulation, gamma-distribution

I have two overlapping gamma distributions, 'a' and 'b', the upper tail of 'b' overlaps the lower tail of 'a'. I want to randomly sample pairs of values, one from each distribution.

However, there is a physical relation between all sampled pairs such that 'a' must always be greater than 'b'. How can I enforce this condition without messing up the randomness/distribution of my samples?

If I simply reject all cases where 'b' > 'a' and keep re-sampling until 'b' < 'a' it seems that would in each case be artificially sampling 'b' from a specific region (everything < 'a') and thus cause the histogram of 'b' samples to not represent the original specified gamma distribution.

Comment: You'll need to specify the joint distribution of the two random variables.  Maybe you can characterize what you have in the following manner.  Suppose $X\sim \Gamma(a_X,b)$ and $Y\sim \Gamma(a_Y,b)$ with $X$ and $Y$ being independent (but with the same scale parameter $b$).  Then $Z=X+Y$ also has a gamma distribution with parameters $a_X+a_Y$ and $b$.  So the pair of random variables $(X,Z)$ has the properties that you describe:  Z > X and both have gamma distributions.

Comment: If you are going to ask the same question simultaneously on two different forums, then please reference the other post. Otherwise if an answer or instructive comment appears on one site, the folks on the other site won't know that. That results in you wasting others valuable time.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66925092/scipy-randomly-sample-from-two-distributions-but-with-one-value-always-greater

Comment: A correlation coefficient of $1$ is possible only when these Gamma distributions differ in their scale factor.  Is that indeed the case?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do what you're asking. If you enforce the hard condition, you will effectively change the distribution. You can still retain some "randomness", but the two distributions will clearly be dependent.

Comment: @Adrian The question doesn't appear to require independence, because it refers to a "physical relation," indicating a lack of independence.

Comment: @whuber: True, but the phrase "random sample" always refers to iid distributions, right? Maybe I'm extrapolating out too much with the word "random", but it definitely seems to me that the "quality of the randomness", or whatever is the appropriate term, will certainly be less if the condition is enforced versus if it's not.

Comment: @Adrian "Random sample" in this context would be a sample of the *bivariate* distribution: "I want to randomly sample **pairs of values,** one from each distribution."

Comment: @whuber: Ah, gotcha. Thanks!